# Grails Server Sent Event

Tags: javascript, grails, server-sent-events

I need to get Server-sent-events working with Grails. I feel like I am close, but just not quite there. The JavaScript request successfully reaches the controller, but it throws an error every time. It keeps retrying once every 2 seconds or so (probably due to the error).

I need to send an event to the user when the server's session timer gets below 5 minutes. I am trying to use HTML5's EventSource because I only want to send a single request to the server (multiple requests will reset the session timer each time). According to [Lean Java Engineering](https://leanjavaengineering.wordpress.com/), HTML5 meets my need.

-**Javascript**-

```
console.log("Starting eventSource");
var eventSource = new EventSource("SSETest/push");
console.log("Started eventSource");
eventSource.onmessage   = function(event) { console.log("Message received: " + event.data); };
eventSource.onopen      = function(event) { console.log("Open " + event); };
eventSource.onerror     = function(event) { console.log("Error " + event); };
console.log("eventState: " + eventSource.readyState);
// Stop trying after 10 seconds of errors
setTimeout(function() {eventSource.close();}, 10000);
```

-**Grails Controller**-

```
package sessionManager
class SSETestController {
    def push = {
        println "$request made it!"
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream, charset=UTF-8")
        response << "data: the data"
        render "HI"
    }
}
```

-**Grails Console**-

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4f889fad made it!
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@13f78b8c made it!
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4b50734c made it!
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4c4bde24 made it!
```

-**JavaScript Console**-

```
Starting eventSource
Started eventSource
eventState: 0
Open [object Event] 
Error [object Event] 
Open [object Event] 
Error [object Event]
Open [object Event] 
Error [object Event]
Open [object Event]
Error [object Event]
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris Hancock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Grails controller, you need to change to something like this :

```
package sessionManager
class SSETestController {
    def push = {
        println "$request made it!"
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream, charset=UTF-8")
        //response << "data: the data\n\n"
        render "data: the data\n\n"
    }
}
```

In its basic form, the response should contain a "data:" line, followed by your message, followed by two "\n" characters to end the stream:

```
data: My message\n\n
```

Now the response in console is :

```
Starting eventSource
Started eventSource
eventState: 0
Open [object Event]
Message received: the data
Error [object Event]
Open [object Event]
Message received: the data
Error [object Event]
Open [object Event]
Message received: the data
Error [object Event]
Open [object Event]
Message received: the data
Error [object Event]
```

For more details you can look on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/.

**UPDATE**

> Why does it throw an error every time, though?

There can be different reason for error for example : network timeout. In our case, it is due to connection being closed between server and browser.

> Why does it continually ping the server?

The connection between server and browser is closed after browser gets `the data`. So the browser tries to reconnect roughly 3 seconds after each connection is closed.

> I thought HTML5 was supposed to connect once when the JavaScript ran
>   the first time, and receive events as long as the controller sent
>   them.

It is supposed to have always connection with server but not connect once.
Yes, it receives events as long as the controller sent them message. But in our case the server/controller just send `data: the data\n\n` and connection is closed.
In order to receive message continuously, you need to have loop in the controller action. For example :

```
package sessionManager
class SSETestController {
    def push = {
        println "$request made it!"
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream, charset=UTF-8")
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
            render "data: the data\n\n"
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
        render "data: finished\n\n"
    }
}
```

You can also use `while(true)` loop.

If you want to more about `onerror`, you can see this link http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/receive-updates-from-the-server-using-the-eventsource.html.
According to above link,

> There is an onerror() event handler, but it's not as useful as you
>   might think. It can however tell us some things about what's
>   happening, thanks to the EventSource's readyState property. For
>   instance, a value of EventSource.CONNECTING means that the connection
>   was lost and the EventSource is attempting to reconnect. If something
>   goes very wrong, a value of EventSource.CLOSED will let you know.
>   Other than that, you can't get much information as there is no error
>   object to query. Instead, it is the event object itself that is passed
>   to the handler. The EventSource may be accessed via the eventSource or
>   eventTarget properties, since both point to the same object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why does it throw an error every time, though? And why does it continually ping the server? I thought HTML5 was supposed to connect once when the JavaScript ran the first time, and receive events as long as the controller sent them and the page was loaded?

Comment: Thank you, Ramsharan! I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Ramsharan, if I follow your last example (with the for loop) I can see the messages are NOT sent until the controller-action is actually finished (the last render line). When so, the browser receives ALL messages at once. Is there a way to release the messages while preventing the connection to be closed?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Grails 3.2 there is native support for Server Sent Events via the [RxJava plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/rxjava).

An [example application](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rxjava/tree/master/examples/server-sent-event-example) is available too, as well as a guide on the [grails guides page](https://guides.grails.org/server-sent-events/guide/index.html).